# Using lambda operator allows the return of void values

Tags: c#, lambda

It is to my understanding that the lambda operator can be used to turn code like this:

```
static int Add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Into code like this:

```
static int Add(int a, int b)
    => a + b;
```

However while messing around with this I discovered that it can be used to return void values, which would normally not be allowed. Code like this would usually throw an error:

```
static void Func()
{
    return VoidFunc();
}
static void VoidFunc()
{
    // Doesn't return a value
}
```

However this works just fine:

```
static void Function()
    => VoidFunc();

static void VoidFunc()
{
    // Doesn't return a value
}
```

I was just wondering if there what is happening here and if there is something I'm not understanding

Comment: I don't really understand the question. In your first example you tried to *return* the 'void' value so it throws, but in the second example ..Function() => ... is the same as ..Function() { ... } and is not a lambda expression but and 'Expression body definition'. Feel free to [check out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator) the MSDN article about it

Comment: Additionally, while @Fabjan is correct, it's also worth noting that the logical behavior of the `=>` token is actually the same between expression bodied members and lambda expressions. C# doesn't treat `void` as a proper type and thus `return somethingThatReturnsVoid` is not valid while `=> somethingThatReturnsVoid` is valid. However, this difference is really the result of how the language has evolved over time. See `public delegate TResult Func<T, TResult>(T x);` vs `public delegate void Action<T>(T x);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `void` lambda/method(*) doesn't "do" a `return`. It needs no return value, so it just calls the other lambda/method, regardless if that lambda/method returns something or not.

And the (*): it's actually a method like any other, just created using expression body syntax which resembles how we write lambda expressions, which is possible because the C# compiler was built to support it.

For more info see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members.